# How to make apk create by phonegap work on all android device?

Tags: phonegap

I used Phonegap to make a "hello word" apk. My app run in android 4.4 but I can't intall it in my android 2.2 phone.
Can I make my app work for old android device?

this is my config.xml: [config.xml](http://doctorgame.mygamesonline.org/config.xml)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set *minSdkVersion* to the corresponding one

From [Phonegap official documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/phonegap-build/configuring/preferences/#android-minSdkVersion)

> **android-minSdkVersion**: Minimum Android SDK version. Corresponds to the usesSdk attributes in the *AndroidManifest.xml* file - more details are in the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html). **Defaults to 14 (Android >= 4.0)**.

The default value is set to work on android above 4.0 ICS

From [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html)

The syntax is

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="integer"
          android:targetSdkVersion="integer"
          android:maxSdkVersion="integer" />
```

Here you need to set the value

For 2.2, the *minSdkVersion* value should be *8*

So, set it as

```
android:minSdkVersion="8"
```

In manifest, it'll look like

```
<manifest>
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: where can i find "AndroidManifest.xml" ? I use phonegap latest version and i just see "config.xml" in local path, i try to change value "14" to "1" (8 not work) in this line: <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />  .My app can intall but can not run.

Comment: did you used any API call that doesn't available in lower android versions? or what is your target sdk version

Comment: i uploaded my config.xml ,i hope it give more information to help me.

Comment: little busy will look into it soon. @MinhDr